# How to Concatenate Variable In Sass?

Tags: sass

I work with bootstrap 4 and I want to make `direction` to `rtl` so I made 3 variables: `$direction: rtl;` `$left:left;` and `$right:right;`

`@if($direction == rtl){ $left : right; $right : left; }`

I want to change left with variable `$left` in this is  text:

```
 margin-left: 0;
 @include border-left-radius($border-radius);
```

My try:

```
 margin-#{$left}: 0;  // is correct
 @include border-#{$left}-radius($border-radius);  // is wrong
```

How to write it?

Comment: Why not using the position as a parameter of the mixin ?

Comment: i work with bootstrap and i want make direction to rtl 
so i make 3 variable  
$direction: rtl;
$left:left;
$right:right;

@if($direction == rtl){
  $left : right;
  $right : left;
}

Comment: You should consider doing it another way because it is simply impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used @if and @else and it work fine

```
@if(true){
    @include border-left-radius($border-radius);
}@else{
    @include border-right-radius($border-radius);
}
```